How to implement vertical split panels in Angular?
I want to implement vertical split panels in angular project such that there are two panels separated by splitter div and when dragged on this splitter the views are resized that means when I drag upwards the below view gets bigger and when dragged downwards the above view gets bigger
I searched and tried to implement using libraries like primeng but not working
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-resizable',
  templateUrl: './resizable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resizable.component.css']
})
export class ResizableComponent {}


<p-splitter 
    [style]="{ height: '300px' }"
    layout="vertical">
        <ng-template pTemplate>
            <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                Panel 1
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate>
            <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                Panel 2
            </div>
        </ng-template>
</p-splitter>`

.card {
    background: var(--surface-card);
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

error: Error: node_modules/primeng/splitter/splitter.d.ts:156:75 - error TS2344: Type '{ styleClass: { alias: "styleClass"; required: false; }; panelStyleClass: { alias: "panelStyleClass"; required: false; }; style: { alias: "style"; required: false; }; panelStyle: { alias: "panelStyle"; required: false; }; ... 6 more ...; panelSizes: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string; }'. Property '"styleClass"' is incompatible with index signature. Type '{ alias: "styleClass"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

there is a working example on primeng stackblitz please share the issue you are facing, also share the code!

could you reshare the stackblitz where the issue happens for checking!

I don't know how to share on stackblitz, can you please review the above code and error
